# Is there any relationship between the vector defined as a vector or line matrix and the vector defined in physics?

Tags: vectors, matrix-calculus

I initially knew the definition of vector in my high school physics class, in which it's defined as a geometry model which has a magnitude and a direction. Now I'm studying deep learning and has seen the definition of matrix, in which a vector is defined as either a row or a column of a matrix(correct me if I'm wrong).

If there any relationship between these two kinds of vectors? Are they the same thing? I tend to think that the vector introduced in my physics class can either be a 2D or 3D vector, which can be represented as a tuple of 2 numbers or 3 numbers, while for the vector defined in matrix, the amount of the numbers in this vector represents its dimension as well. In this case I think they are the same thing, but just have different dimensions. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at [this 3blue1brown video](https://youtu.be/TgKwz5Ikpc8) where he discusses this exact topic. It's the last video in a series, so there might be some things he mentions that you are unfamiliar with, but the overall discussion of what makes a vector should be possible to follow regardless.

Comment: Of course there is a relationship. Whether it is the equivalence depends on the exact meaning of the expression "same thing". In any case both things belong to linear spaces (they obey same rules of addition and multiplication by scalar).

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate your help and answers!!

Comment: Thank you @Arthur for pointing me to that video that indeed explains very detailedly and solved my confusion. Also for any other who may have the same question, I also find this video to be useful [What is vector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbBDToXjBw&list=PLJHszsWbB6hrkmmq57lX8BV-o-YIOFsiG&index=5). The uploader stated that those arrows interpretation of vectors is just one kind of vectors called Euclidean vector. The "array" interpretation of the vectors is actually representing their "components". More details in the video.